# Is there an appropriate mechanism to say thank you on this site?

Tags: feature-request, off-topic

I understand that not cluttering up the questions and answers with "thank yous" and "me toos" is important to ensure clarity and stay on topic. Indeed it is a great feature of this site. Is there an appropriate way of saying thank you to a particularly helpful editor/commentator/answerer?

Comment: I express thanks by pointing out the part of the answer that I think is the most important. Also, of course, there's voting and selecting too.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The obvious way to say "Thank you" is with an up-vote!

When that isn't sufficient, a comment can be made, but most "Thank you" comments will eventually be deleted by moderators, as they don't really contribute to the long-term value of the site.

If you feel an answer really deserves an extra big "Thank You," you can also open a bounty on the question to award between 50 and 500 reputation to the deserving answer.

Comment: Thank you....;)

Comment: Too bad I can't award a bounty on Meta. You'd get one for this answer.

Comment: @DavidStratton: You can always award a bounty on one of my other answers on the main site... ;)

Comment: Good answer but it'll be a while before I can offer a bounty without destroying my ability to actually use the site!

Comment: @Reluctant_Linux_User: Ah, don't be so **reluctant**... hehe :)  (And welcome to the site!)